# iOS: How to write handler for Tap Gesture Recognizer if dragged in from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image and in the storyboard I've dragged a `Tap Gesture Recognizer` on top of this image and changed the settings:

For my TGR:

[image]

For my image:

[image]

How do I hook this up to my controller now? I want a method to fire off when the double tap happens. Is there some sort of protocol I have to conform to? Do people normally do this from the storyboard or programmatically in `viewDidLoad`? I don't mind doing it another way if that's the general trend of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect the gesture recognizer as a outlet to your ViewController and in your viewDidLoad :

```
    [self.yourGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnImage:)] ;
```

and then declare your method didTapOnImage method :

```
-(void)didTapOnImage:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    //do your work here
}
```